# OnClickListener of a fragment is getting fired in another fragment too

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I am implementing swipeable tabs.I have 3 tabs.In last tab there are 4 buttons which on click will start another fragment activity.But when i click on free space in 2nd tab the same onclick is getting fired.Please help me with this isuue.

Here is my comple project link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3znk-VNWY6RUHVvdDBpNWlmN3M

```
AlbumsFragment

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlbumsFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    View view;
    Button albums,songs,artists,playlist;
    Activity thisActivity;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_albums, container,false);
        thisActivity=getActivity();
        albums=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_albums);
        songs=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_allsongs);
        artists=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_artists);
        playlist=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_playlist);
        albums.setOnClickListener(AlbumsFragment.this);
        songs.setOnClickListener(AlbumsFragment.this);
        artists.setOnClickListener(AlbumsFragment.this);
        playlist.setOnClickListener(AlbumsFragment.this);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_albums:

            Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "in", 100).show();
            Intent i=new Intent(thisActivity,PlayList.class);
            thisActivity.startActivity(i);
            thisActivity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.flip_left_to_right, R.anim.flip_right_to_left);


            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

This onclicklistener is getting fired in adjacent fragment.

RecorderFragment

```
package com.krazzyplayer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class RecordFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_audio_recorder, container, false);

        return view;
    }



}
```

Comment: What you describe isn't possible. Post the code for whatever your 'adjacent' `Fragment` is.

Comment: I too got shocked when i got see this thing.Please provide some suggestion

Comment: this looks impossible. try giving different ids to your resource elements(although this should not matter, I would try this first)

Comment: I am maintanining different ids

Comment: Post the layouts of your frags.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3znk-VNWY6RUHVvdDBpNWlmN3M....     Here is my complete project file.Please run and check.

Comment: the project you shared was too many errors and too large, if possible, I suggest you to extract the problematic source code as a small project then share with us, that may get help quickly than before.

Answer (score 0):

disable onClick method for fragments that are not visible. To do this add this code-

```
if(!getUserVisibleHint())
{return false;}
```

Before the 1st line of OnClick method on every fragment, so that OnClick method will not be executed if fragment is not visible.

Comment: if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
   
   albums.setOnClickListener(AlbumsFragment.this);
   songs.setOnClickListener(AlbumsFragment.this);
   artists.setOnClickListener(AlbumsFragment.this);
   playlist.setOnClickListener(AlbumsFragment.this);
  }                                  I did like this.if i click on that tab particular tab then onclick event is getting fired successfully but when i scroll through remaining fragments onclick event is not getting fired  even in its own fragment.@user1517029

Comment: Please put the code inside onClickMethod() as suggested and try.You are doing something else.